# php when clicked on the link showing The requested URL /filename was not found on this server

Tags: php, .htaccess

There was one php project which was made in core php. Now my work is to change some stylesheet issues. So I just downloaded all the files with the database. After that I just made all the setup on my localhost(LAMP). Then I just browsed the page, I saw the home page is showing correctly. But when I just clicked on any of the link, I just got an error like

```
Not Found

The requested URL /filename.php was not found on this server.

Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

To check the issue when I used `tail /var/log/apache2/error.log` command to see the error log. I just saw

```
[error] [client 127.0.0.1] script '/var/www/filename.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: http://localhost/path to the project folder/
```

So can someone kindly tell me what is the wrong here? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks ...

**Update**

When I downloaded the file my `.htaccess` file was something like this

```
#suPHP_ConfigPath /home/demosite/public_html
<IfModule mod_php4.c>
php_value session.use_trans_sid 0
php_value session.cookie_time 3600
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 3600
#php_value session.cookie_domain ".demosite.com"
</IfModule>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+)\.html $1.php
#RewriteRule 404\.shtml$ 404.php
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}<>%{REQUEST_URI} ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)\.demosite\.com<>/([^/]*) 
RewriteCond %1<>%3 !^(.*)<>\1$ [NC]
RewriteRule   ^(.*)$ - [E=USER:%1]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^demosite\.com 
RewriteCond %{ENV:USER} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) company_index.php?uid=%1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([A-Za-z0-9]+)\.demosite\.com 
RewriteRule ^(.*) company_index.php?uid=%1

RewriteRule categories\/([a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+)\.html browsecats.php?browse=$1
RewriteRule categories\/([a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+)\/([0-9]+)\/([a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+)\.html browsecats.php?browse=$1&cid=$2
RewriteRule listings\/([a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+)\.html listings.php?browse=$1
RewriteRule listings\/([a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+)\/([0-9]+)\.html listings.php?browse=$1&pg=$2
RewriteRule listings\/([a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+)\/([0-9]+)\/([a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+)\.html listings.php?browse=$1&cid=$2
RewriteRule listings\/([a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+)\/([0-9]+)\/([a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+)\/([0-9]+)\.html listings.php?browse=$1&cid=$2&pg=$4
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+)\.htm$ $1.html
```

here demosite is the sitename. I have replaced that

Comment: What is `path to the project folder/` the `/filename.php` implies `http://localhost/filename.php`

Comment: http://localhost/path to the project folder/ implies the folders and sub folders to the project directory which is in the www folder

Answer (score 0):

As you have also added .htaccess to your tags im assuming your using it,

if it has `RewriteBase /` but your project is in a subdir make sure that the subdir is added to that else rewrite will look for the file in the wrong directory
so add your:

```
RewriteBase /path_to_the_project_folder
```

Comment: thanks for the reply..Let us assume that I have my project inside the folder like /var/www/projects then what will be the rule for that?

Comment: `RewriteBase /projects` if its in a sub dir of projects, like `/var/www/projects/work1` then `RewriteBase /projects/work1`